# Open AI 1.3.6 changes, code running much slower

Tags: python, openai-api

I have a csv file with a column that has a question in it that pertains to that specific row. I use OpenAI to generate the answer to that question. Prior to the update, each answer took about 1-2 seconds to generate so overall time for a 20 row file took about 30 seconds. Making what I thought were the required updates, it now takes almost 6 minutes to complete. Here is the relevant code:

```
##OpenAI Defaults
TEMPERATURE: 1
OPENA_AI_MODEL: gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct
max_tokens: 200
n_value: 1
stop: None
presence_penalty: 0
frequency_penalty: 0.1
```

```
import openai
from openai import OpenAI
load_dotenv()

client = OpenAI()
# AI description function
def openai_completion(question):
    response = client.completions.create(
        model=config["OPENA_AI_MODEL"],
        prompt=question,
        temperature=config["TEMPERATURE"],
        max_tokens=config["max_tokens"],
        n=config["n_value"],
        stop=config["stop"],
        presence_penalty=config["presence_penalty"],
        frequency_penalty=config["frequency_penalty"],
    )
    return response.choices[0].text.strip()
    #return response["choices"][0]["text"].strip() **Old line replaced by line above**

csv["Description"] = csv["Question"].apply(openai_completion)
```

How could I figure out what is slowing this down? If I have the adjustments for 1.3.6 updated correctly, etc? The code works, like I said, just really slow.

Comment: This is almost 100% remote. You _could_ use a sampling profiler to measure where the time is being sent, but the work all happens on OpenAI's end; you'll almost certainly find that it's just being spent waiting for OpenAI to return results, nothing within your code's control. (How heavy load happens to be on any given day _is_, in practice, a thing that fluctuates).

Comment: If OpenAI is being slow and you have an Azure account, think about using Microsoft's version of OpenAI services (running on MS servers vs OpenAI-owned ones) via Azure -- and creating deployments in different regions to compare performance between them. Again, it's normal for this to vary hour-to-hour and day-to-day, sometimes quite severely; it's extremely unlikely that your API version update has anything to do with the performance problem.